# How to Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header?

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, seo, gzip

Google and pingdom.com says i should 
 "Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header"

i do not know or understand how to do this. Can anyone explain what it is and what it does?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am getting nearly 100% score in https://tools.pingdom.com/ and https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

I found a helpful post to speed up wordpress website or blog https://www.keycdn.com/blog/speed-up-wordpress/

With some other optimizations, I am also using below code on my site in `.htaccess` file (usually hidden in main website folder)

My Server is Apache, You can check in hosting control panel (Like cPanel/WHM Panel)(if your server is nginx check keycdn.com post)

(Copy and paste below code in .htaccess file, it's working good for me)

(Upvote this answer if works for you)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg|js|ico)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This got me from a C -> B (on the page header metric)...now getting msg about using cookies (although I have a simple one page app..gunna keep dialing it..but this helped me a lot!)

Comment: to reduce the deflate stuff, you can use:<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|ttf|html|xml|plain)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Answer (score 16):

I think you have to enable compression for specific files like `css`, `js` and `xml`.
The following code added to your domain's root .htaccess file will enable this kind of feature on you server:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

If you would like to add more file type to this rule, just simple add the its extension to the statement! `<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz|newone)$">`

Comment: i added that code to my .htaccess file but my website is still not gzipped what wront can you help .. i contacted the my hosting company and they are a bunch of idiots saying htaccess shouldnt be in the root of the website in the first place!!! crazy

Comment: I don't know whats the problem. You should insert the code to an empty [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) (must be in the same directory as index.html/index.php) file. Maybe it will work and you can find out what the problem is. Try [this tool](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) to test the compression. Maybe the browser caching make some problem.

Comment: There's a typo in your code — you need the colon after 'Vary': `Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding`

Answer (score 3):

I also had problems with this not working

Wht happened was I had another header directive for my php files

I had a Header set Cache-control - and it overwrites the Header append Vary, so you have to put them in the same block.
What I had to do was set the Vary for all the other files in one Filesmatch statement and the Cache and Vary for the php files in a separate FilesMatch statement like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gz)$">
 Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=300"
 Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

That's not my actual Cache-Control statement - just simplified for the example code.